# problems with http response headers Angular

Tags: angular, api, http, postman

I’m trying to get the access_token value from HTTP petition to API. Whenever I make the petition, I always get an empty value. If I try from curl or postman, the returned value is always correct. Does anyone have an idea of what’s happening?

Angular version 7.2.16

HTTP request with postman
[image]

HTTP request with Angular app
[image]

Comment: You looking in the dev tools, can you actual `console.log` the response header. I memory serves right (and I tried to find it) is that the dev tools don't show the token anymore if not  hand-shaked through https.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

thanks!

it's a problem with a backend when the backend receives a batch of petitions don't return access_token